# MAgento CSV example for MagMI

Tags: magento, magmi

Hi I'm trying to make a CSV file to run a product import with Magmi.

Previous answers suggest that I export a CSV from magento to get an example.  However it I'm running Magento 1.6, I think the CSV format in v1.6 has changed quite a bit and is no longer recognised by MagMI.  For instance, magento now export categories as full names rather than a simple category id.

Could someone share a CSV with me that would work?

Comment: Magmi has magento cersion selection in global configuration options

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 different CSV formats used in Magento: the dataflow format and the new (not so robust) format you're referring to. Magmi will only work with the dataflow format.

The easiest way to figure out how the format looks like is by exporting a CSV in the dataflow format. To do this do the following in the Magento backend: System -> Import/Export -> Dataflow profiles -> Export all products -> Run profile. You can then download the csv file via FTP, you'll find it in var/export.

Answer (score 1):

Magmi will only work with the dataflow forma so magmi need some structured for import base with column name with required field.

[Download csv example Hear.](https://understandinge.com/wp-content/sp-resources/forum-file-uploads/administrator/2014/05/MASTER_TESTFILE-Example.csv)

[Configurable Product csv for import](https://understandinge.com/wp-content/sp-resources/forum-file-uploads/wcg_rv/2015/12/example_sizecolour_variations.csv)